# augmented reality - converting 2d coordinates of a known model to 3d

Tags: 3d, augmented-reality, projection, perspective

I am starting to work on an augmented reality project but I am starting from scratches.
I want to do something like that:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6Jvvn7s6rbw
I have tried reading on augmented reality and perspective projection but I could not find anything about calculating the distance from the image/paper that I am putting on the table or how to convert it's coordinates from 2d to 3d(which is basically the same).
Basically I want to put an image which I know it's real high and width on a table and by using this I want to calculate the distance and angel from my camera to the image.

I am not looking for an answer from you of how to actually do it, but where could I find these answers? What subjects do I need to look for in google? Because as far as I see "augmented reality" and "perspective projection" isn't enough.